# Filtering Ansible Output to get specific result

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible playbook, to gather facts from NAT Rules. The playbook works as expected:

```
- name: Get Facts from NAT Rules
  hosts: panorama
  connection:  local
  gather_facts:  False
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    
  
  collections:
    - paloaltonetworks.panos

  tasks:
    - name: Get a list of all NAT rules
      panos_nat_rule_facts:
        provider: '{{ provider }}'
        listing: True 
        device_group: PA-02
        rulebase: post-rulebase
      register: nat_rules 

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ nat_rules.listing }}'
```

The output of the playbook, provides the facts from the NAT Rules, however, I would interested in getting only the value of the snat_static_address and nothing else:

```
ok: [10.1.10.100] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "description": null,
            "destination_dynamic_translated_address": null,
            "destination_dynamic_translated_distribution": null,
            "destination_dynamic_translated_port": null,
            "destination_ip": [
                "any"
            ],
            "destination_zone": [
                "wan"
            ],
            "disabled": null,
            "dnat_address": null,
            "dnat_port": null,
            "group_tag": null,
            "ha_binding": null,
            "nat_type": null,
            "negate_target": false,
            "rule_name": "NAT_01",
            "service": "any",
            "snat_address_type": null,
            "snat_bidirectional": true,
            "snat_dynamic_address": null,
            "snat_interface": null,
            "snat_interface_address": null,
            "snat_static_address": "74.120.99.147",
            "snat_type": "static-ip",
            "source_ip": [
                "10.1.10.10"
            ],
            "source_translation_fallback_interface": null,
            "source_translation_fallback_ip_address": null,
            "source_translation_fallback_ip_type": null,
            "source_translation_fallback_translated_addresses": null,
            "source_translation_fallback_type": null,
            "source_zone": [
                "lan"
            ],
            "tag_val": null,
            "target": null,
            "to_interface": null,
            "uuid": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter this output to retrieve the value of: snat_static_address.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `{{ nat_rules.listing | map(attribute='snat_static_address') }}` will give you a list of all returned values. You can use `| first` if you only want the first one.... or loop over those values if you are interrested in all of them (in case your module retruns several depending on remote router state)... or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference the value with the following syntax

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ nat_rules.listing | map(attribute="snat_static_address") }}'
```